# How should the first n natural numbers be arranged in a circle to minimize the sum of the products of adjacent pairs?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, inequalities, quadratic-forms

I was able to  find (and prove) arrangements that would result in the sum of the products of adjacent pairs attain the maximum.

I am able to conjecture that the arrangement that would result in the minimum sum of products of adjacent pairs: begin with 1 and 2, squeeze n between the two. We can have 1 in the clockwise direction and 2 in the anticlockwise direction of n. We can then add n-1 traversing in clockwise direction of 1. we can then add 3 (clockwise from n-1), then add ( n-2 clockwise from 3),...

I have tried a few different ways of trying to prove that this arrangement is the desired minimal arrangement but all proofs have broken down. Would be great if someone could throw some light.

Comment: This is essentially problem 10725 from the American Mathematical Monthly. You can look up the solution here https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695399

Comment: That was quite helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I noticed, however, that the minimal arrangement is different from the one I  conjectured. I essentially looked at a few cases and generaized. I wonder if there is some transparent process through which one might arrive at the arrangement proposed in the solution. As it stands, it seems a bit opaque how one might arrive at the proposed arrangement,